# 010 Editor template: convert a int to wchar_t

Tags: c, string, wchar-t, wstring, hex-editors

I'm reading a single `wchar_t` character from a binary file in 010 template in this way

```c
wchar_t character;
```

it will give me for example **64** for @, after that I need to add **0x20** to the **64** so it should be **96** now
my question is how can I convert the output after `add` operation to wchar_t (or string) again in 010 template?

Comment: In C, characters (both `char` and `wchar_t`) are integers.  So you don't have to do anything special to do arithmetic on them, or to "convert" them back and forth from integers.

Comment: @SteveSummit 010 template are a specials format for parsing binary file [read more here](https://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/manual/IntroTempScripts.htm), its like C/C+ structure in most of ways, btw if they both integer so how can I show them? because if I print them manually it just show the int and not the character (010 Template also have printf and sprintf)

Comment: When you print an integer using `%d` you see its integer value.  When you print with `%c` you see its character value.  Or for `wchar_t` there's `%lc`.

Comment: @SteveSummit sadly looks lilke `%lc` not supported in 010 template